# Bootstrap grid configure correct alignment

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm using the bootstrap grid system, and I'm trying to get a correct view on both wide windows (desktop, tablet) and narrow windows (mobile screens).

What I want on wide screens is this:

```
[image 1][image 2][text 1]
[image 3][image 4][text 2]
```

On a mobile I'd like to see this:

```
[image 1][image 2]
[image 3][image 4]
[text 1] [text 2]
```

What I'm currently getting on mobile or narrow desktop windows is:

```
[image 1][image 2]
[text 1]
[image 3][image 4]
[text 2]
```

Here is a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/s8u9ehat/). The code is also below:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

          <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Panel Header</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="" height="128" width="128"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="" height="128" width="128"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 border border-primary">
                            some text.........
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="" height="128" width="128"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="" height="128" width="128"/>
                        </div>              
                        <div class="col-md-3 border border-primary">
                            some text.........
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css for text

```
position:absolute;
```

and change location text.
or create one div and put in texts and set display:none when screen change to mobile set show and hide default texts.

Comment: I was hoping to fix it using correct column codes, such as ´col-xs-6´ etc.